# Oracle deleting tables

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is it possible to delete automatically records from parent table when I delete connected records in child table in Oracle 10g. I found that I can remove child records when I delete connected parent records using ON DELETE CASCADE, but can I do reverse action?

Comment: either go for FLASHBACK or store the records in a table through a trigger just like audit

Comment: Do you mean to automatically remove the parent when the last child is removed?

Answer (score 0):

Can the child table contain several child objects per parent? If not, simply define the delete constraint the other way around